# To parse with the help of atom parsing

Tags: android, rss, feedparser, android-parser

i have to parse this type of xml..

```
 <content type="xhtml">
        <apxh:div>
            <apxh:p>blah..blah...blah</apxh:p>
            <apxh:p>blah..blah...blah</apxh:p>
        </apxh:div>
 </content>
```

How can i parse it by atom parsing (root handler, element handler).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you take a look at this article.
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/

also just found this 
Open Source Android atom \ rss reader 
http://code.google.com/p/android-feed-reader/source/browse/#

How to create and parse Rss Feed
http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0556.html